# django [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, django

I've built a script to read an excel file and save the contents into my database.  (Note: the file and the script are in different directories).  However, when I try to execute the script from my views.py as a simple import, django throws an error that it cannot find the file or directory:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\media\\documents\\GDRAT.xls\\'
```

My actual code in the script looks like this:

```
source_wb = xlrd.open_workbook('media/documents/GDRAT.xls')
```

Where my script is in the parent directory.  Executing the script from the command line works just fine, so I'm struggling with why django is reading it differently.

My `views.py` function looks like this (Note: I go back to the parent directory to find the script - which seems to work fine, just can't find the excel file I need to read in):

```
def UpdateGDRAT(request):
    os.chdir('..')
    import GDRAT
    return render_to_response('success.html')
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the script is GDRAT.py

Comment: Why are you not joining it with the directory `media/` is under?

Comment: Have you tired opening it with xlrd *outside* of django? In a shell or terminal?

Answer (score 10):

**This works for me**

```
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'media/documents/GDRAT.xls')
```

Answer (score 4):

settings.py 
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

```
from django.conf import settings
import os


base_dir =settings.MEDIA_ROOT    
my_file = os.path.join(base_dir, str(GDRAT.xls))
```

Answer (score 3):

when you run a script from the terminal, you have a current working directory from which any relative path starts, when calling the same script from another code your working directory could be different.

If you know the position of the file relative to the script, I suggest you to use an absolute path constructed dynamically like this:

```
import os
GDRAT_abs_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'media/documents/GDRAT.xls')
```

__file__ gives you the path of the current file that is the script (assuming this line is placed in the script);
for dirname see http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname
for realpath see http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath

Comment: I'm trying to implement this solution, but doesn't the (_file_) add my script to the path?  When I print GDRAT_abs_path (to see what's happening) in the terminal, I see GDRAT.py/media/documents..etc..  How can I escape out of GDRAT.py but still use the dynamic path?

Comment: btw - i was able to use this, but had to slice the GDRAT.py out of the GDRAT_abs_path and create an alternative object - kinda bulky but worked..

Comment: oops, you are right :) I should have wrapped os.path.realpath in os.path.dirname, I fixed the answer

Comment: you also should use os.path.join instead of hard-coding the path separator, as a rule of thumb never use "/" in path operations in python.

Comment: I know this post is an oldie, but it still solved my problem. Thanks!