# how to convert format of my .pdf file to .txt in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, pypdf

I am working on a Django web-application, where I want to convert .pdf and .docx files to .txt  .
I wrote a save() function where I want to get the file and then convert it into .txt format . But it is giving me the error that :

> FileNotFoundError at /post/new/
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Python String.pdf'

**my models.py is :**

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
import PyPDF2
import os
# Create your models here.
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.file:
            pdffileobj = open(str(self.file.name), 'rb') # this is where i want to get the file but it give me the error 
            pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffileobj)
            x = pdfreader.numPages
            pageobj = pdfreader.getPage(x + 1)
            text = pageobj.extractText()
            file1 = open(self.file.name.txt, "a")
            file1.writelines(text)
        super(FileUpload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

The conclusion is I want to convert my .pdf to .txt before saving it .
**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

i have not worked with django but this code might help:
use os for file path

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'filename')
```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24971898/13319197

Comment: All the code is same but how to read a file using django is the problem. That this code is not reading the file

Comment: @HumaQureshi where did you define self.file.name

Comment: @HumaQureshi you have to providing  full path in the open method

Comment: I do not want to do it statically. I want to do it with every user file

Comment: i found this if it didnt work  i cant think any other way sorry https://stackoverflow.com/a/24971898/13319197