# Django : Media file not found when deleting despite it's correctly written when creating (PROD)

Tags: django, file-upload, settings, delete-file

I've been searching in vain for a long time the origin of this issue.

Everything works well on development : csv file upload + deletion but in production, file is well uploaded when saving my model but it's not found when I want to delete it.

**views.py**  (file_name = sources/newone/egr-2022-light_copie.csv)

```
os.remove(f"media/{str(flow.fl_file_name)}")
```

**settings.py**. (custom settings file for prod)

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
[...]
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/django/httpdocs/gsm2/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**apache conf (+ssl)**

```
[...] 
Alias /static /home/django/httpdocs/gsm2/static
<Directory /home/django/httpdocs/gsm2/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/django/httpdocs/gsm2/media
<Directory /home/django/httpdocs/gsm2/media>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/django/httpdocs/gsm2/gsm2>
[...]
```

I have tried to :

- modify the path used in remove() by removing `media/`... without success.
- modify the path used in remove() by adding `gsm2/`in front of `media/` ... uselessly.
- to replace my settings.py media path with `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`... not better
- Changed folder rights to 777 and ownership to 'django' ... in vain

Any idea about the possible origins of my pains ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround using  [@Naushad solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370298/django-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Replaced :

```
os.remove(f"media/{str(flow.fl_file_name)}")
```

with :

```
file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 
   f"media/{str(flow.fl_file_name)}")
os.remove(file)
```

Still have to analyse this solution for a good understanding.